# "Organic" practices in other fields

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, phrase-requests

In US foods and other products, "organic" simply is a federal certification guaranteeing a set of standards are met. Within the organic product space, differentiators include fair trade, local sourcing, no animal testing, and other practices that appeal to the "conscious consumption" aspect of the field.

What is a way of saying "the 'organic' of X," where X is a field NOT associated with actual organic products? Implying conscious differentiators without spelling them out.

Comment: You're doing this as a metaphor?  "The 'organic' of bowling balls", implying that the bowling balls are made, distributed, produced in a conscientious manner?

Comment: In that case the product could just be called organic bowling balls, since they CAN be produced using organic standards. I suppose I mean something more to the effect of "the organic of email/rideshare/business services."

Comment: There's "environmentally friendly", referring to the impacts of the production and use of the product on the environment.  And "responsibly sourced", which is a bit vaguer, but which includes not employing child labor or purchasing "conflict diamonds", etc.

Comment: So what does it mean to be the organic of business services?  Do you mean better for the environment, or just distinct from run-of-the-mill business services in some way that may appeal to an affluent consumer?

Comment: Appeal to a consumer with standards they would otherwise have to compromise due to lack of available tools or lack of knowledge. Affluent is not a part of it, otherwise white glove might be the better term in the service space.

Comment: [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/organic) gives only 3 senses for the nounal use of _organic_: n.
1. An organic food or a product made from organic materials. // 
2. A substance, especially a fertilizer or pesticide, of animal or vegetable origin. // 
3. Chemistry An organic compound. // I don't see how you arrive at "the 'organic' of X". Do you mean say 'the greenest car on the market'?

Comment: I think @HotLicks has answered you question with regard to two other domains. It' seem to me that the "organic of X" will depend on the domain. Other examples might be "clean coal", Energy Star for appliances, LEED Platinum for buildings, ... If you are looking for a common denominator or hypernym, perhaps "certified" or "accredited" as meeting a set of requirements (embodied in a standard or set of rules, for example), might work.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to use any word involving *organic*, because its meaning has become so fuzzy (except in chemistry) and its use faddish. When I hear someone use using it, my respect for them drops to near zero.

Comment: Well if there actually is a formal certification (the way that USDA Organic is) then you can just use that, as @Richard Kayser writes.  Absent that distinction, I'm not sure what you can do without just writing puffery.

Comment: "socially responsible" as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socially_responsible_investing

Comment: I mean to exploit the fuzziness of "organic" in order to pique interest by introducing it in a non "organic" context. And part of what I have in mind is to implicitly suggest adherence to a body of standards, using USDA Organic AND expectations of other conscious practices. Cadillac as mentioned below implies way too much brand and history, and certainly not the same conscious practices.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth's comment is spot on. You appear to be referring to 'organic' as a product label (used where the producer has chosen to endeavour to attain it and was able to), rather than the broader  meaning of the word. The dichotomy therefore is having or not having the permission to use that label, rather than what actually happened during production. There's nothing fuzzy about that.

Comment: Do note that "organic" is often used (outside of food/medicine) to refer to using intuition or "gut feel" for approaching a problem, vs some "scientific" approach.  Eg, in the computer field one might say "The structure of this program is sort of 'organic'," which would mean that it just sort of grew and therefore has no discernible internal organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider *the **sustainability** of X* as a phrase to identify 'differentiators' along the lines of *organic*, but related to products that *organic* isn't appropriate for.

> **Sustainable** *adjective*
>   1.1 Conserving an ecological balance by avoiding depletion of natural resources:
>   ‘our fundamental commitment to sustainable development’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sustainable)

Here are some examples:

- from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustainable_development):

  > Sustainable development is a process for meeting human development goals while sustaining the ability of natural systems to continue to provide the natural resources and ecosystem services upon which the economy and society depends.
- from the journal [Sustainable Computing](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/sustainable-computing):

  > The aim of Sustainable Computing: Informatics and Systems (SUSCOM) is to publish the myriad research findings related to energy-aware and thermal-aware management of computing resource.
- from [US EPA](https://archive.epa.gov/sustainablemanufacturing/web/html/):

  > Sustainable manufacturing is the creation of manufactured products through economically-sound processes that minimize negative environmental impacts while conserving energy and natural resources.

Answer (score 0):

The *Cadillac* of X.

Cadillac: "The best of its kind; standard of excellence; paragon : Republicans call New York the Cadillac of welfare states/ Revos are the Cadillac of sunglasses" The Dictionary of American Slang, Fourth Edition, which I found at http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cadillac?s=t

Comment: Cadillac is too powerful and old a brand, that context is already taken. It also could be replaced by other cars that have more emotional weight - I'm looking for the same positive weight as organic (emphasis on differentiating conscious practices vs any possible health benefits) without, well, "organic"

Comment: "Cadillac" simply means fancy and expensive.  It's not an adjective that one might use for "responsibly produced" products.

Comment: Clarkson probably suggests a somewhat different definition.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Is there a Britishism here somewhere?  I'm not getting it.

Comment: Clarkson of [Top Gear](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mndX4SyORc) fame. Infamy.